# Grouping sub array's of objects in an array where attribute equals - Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have an array where I am trying to group the `subarray`s of the objects together if the key value pair is equal to `userID`.

Leaving me with one object, per `userID` with all the sub-arrays of that `userID`.

I can't seem to figure out how to do this, even after trawling through SO.

How do I group the subarrays where the `userID`'s are the same?
(the data changes so I need to use a for loop)

Thanks for the help.

The array looks like this:

```
      [  
       {  
          'name':'James',
          'lastname':'Bond',
          'userID': 1001,
          'subarray':[  
             {  
                'color':'blue',
                'animal':'dog'
             }
          ]
       },
       {  
          'name':'James',
          'lastname':'Bond',
          'userID': 1001,
          'subarray':[  
             {  
                'color':'red',
                'animal':'cat'
             }
          ]
       },
       {  
          'name':'Billy',
          'lastname':'King',
          'userID': 1004,
          'subarray':[  
             {  
                'color':'green',
                'animal':'fish'
             }
          ]
       }
    ]
```

I want to make the array like this:

```
      [  
       {  
          'name':'James',
          'lastname':'Bond',
          'userID': 1001,
          'subarray':[  
             {  
                'color':'blue',
                'animal':'dog'
             },
             {  
                'color':'red',
                'animal':'cat'
             }
          ]
       },
       {  
          'name':'Billy',
          'lastname':'King',
          'userID': 1004,
          'subarray':[  
             {  
                'color':'green',
                'animal':'fish'
             }
          ]
       }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a simple iteration.

**Ex:**

```
result = {}
for item in data:
    if item["userID"] not in result:
        result[item["userID"]] = {'name':item["name"], 'lastname':item["lastname"],'userID': item["userID"],'subarray':[]}
    result[item["userID"]]['subarray'].append(item["subarray"])

print(list(result.values()))
```

**Output:**

```
[{'lastname': 'Bond',
  'name': 'James',
  'subarray': [[{'animal': 'dog', 'color': 'blue'}],
               [{'animal': 'cat', 'color': 'red'}]],
  'userID': 1001},
 {'lastname': 'King',
  'name': 'Billy',
  'subarray': [[{'animal': 'fish', 'color': 'green'}]],
  'userID': 1004}]
```

Comment: is there a way to add items from the subarray? For example if animal equalled a number, how do I sum those numbers and add it to its parent. Thanks.